# Changing board shape in Altium: sliding the edge does not work

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

How can I slide this edge? [image]

According to Altium documentation, I should:"Click anywhere along an edge, away from editing handles, and drag to slide that edge" but it does not work for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change board shape in Altium,

1. Go to your PCBDoc
2. Press 'P', then 'L' (Short for place line)
3. Press TAB to enter properties
4. Set width and layer (mechanical for example at 10 mil width). Press OK
5. Draw the boundary of your board with these settings
6. Once you are done, select this boundary
7. Go to Design >> Board Shape >> Define from selected objects.

Done!!

Comment: This isn't really a fix for the problem, it's just a workaround - another way to designate the board outline

Comment: I agree @DerStrom8. I just find this method easier

Comment: So do I, this is how I always do my board shapes

Answer (score 4):

To enable this edge for changing the board shape, you have to enable all from the Selection Filter.

Then you can edit board shape in Design -> Edit Board Shape.